# How do i call on one of the players in class Player?

Tags: python, class

---

hello everyone.
I have this code here that i have been working on using stackoverflow for support. i have yet come into another problem. I need to call on a player for there turn. How do i do this. if it helps the players have a number assigned to them corrosponding to the time they where created.
thanks in advance, Josh

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, tank_name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.tank_name = tank_name
        self.number = number

players = input('Please type player amount >>> ')

try:
    players = int(players)
except ValueError:
    print('Whoops... ' + players + ' is not a valid number. The auto amount is two players.')
    players = int(2)

number = 0

def new_player(number):
    name = input('What is your name >>> ')
    tank_name = input('What is your tanks name >>> ')
    return Player(name, tank_name, number)

for i in range(0, players):
    number = int(number)
    number = number + 1
    new_player(number)
    print()
    print('Next player or end of player creation.')
    print()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have even tried anything... If you are implementing Classes, you should read up about them and how you can use them. If you try and face an issue, I am sure that the community will be more than willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely dependent on what the player turn entails. Here is your code with a basic player turn functionality.

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, tank_name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.tank_name = tank_name
        self.number = number
    
    def player_turn_method(self):
        pass

players = input('Please type player amount >>> ')

try:
    players = int(players)
except ValueError:
    print('Whoops... ' + players + ' is not a valid number. The auto amount is two players.')
    players = int(2)

number = 0
def new_player(number):
    name = input('What is your name >>> ')
    tank_name = input('What is your tanks name >>> ')
    return Player(name, tank_name, number)

def player_turn(player):
    pass

for i in range(0, players):
    playerList = []
    number = int(number)
    number = number + 1
    playerList.append(new_player(number))
    print()
    print('Next player or end of player creation.')
    print()

# this cycles through the players and plays their turn
for i in range(players):
    player_turn(playerList[i])
    # alternatively you could use a class method:
    # playerList[i].player_turn_method()
```

Note this will only allow each player to play one turn. I will let you implement further logic for playing more than 1 turn.